# Prevent python script from stopping if the server is not connected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, client-server

I have developed a python script which reads streams from multiple cameras and pass it to a server to display information on the frames. But the problem is that the script always fails if even of the ports of the server is not responding. I have tried exception handling but still no luck.

What I want is that if the server port is not responding then the frames must be displayed to the user without any information.

I have used python `requests` module.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

                try:
                    payload = { 
                                "frame":frame, 
                                "timestamp": timestamp
                              }

                    payload = jsonpickle.encode(payload)
                    lock.acquire()
                    response = requests.post(self.frame_target_ip, data=payload,          #self.frame_target_ip is the server ip with port number
                                            headers=self.headers)
                    lock.release()

                    objects = jsonpickle.decode(response.content)
                    self.event_data, self.dets = self.parse_objects(objects)

                    if self.show_bounding_box == True:
                        draw_frame = self.draw_bounding_boxes(self.frame, self.dets)
                        self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(draw_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error("Couldn't reach the frame_target_ip", exc_info=True)
```

I am using python 3 and windows 10.

Below is error traceback

```
00:31:52:327-root-INFO--Application Started
00:32:07:682-root-ERROR--Couldn't reach the frame_target_ip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000295D3350E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000295D3350E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Deepanshu/Desktop/VIDS_1cam/UI_1cam.py", line 221, in set_frame
    headers=self.headers)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000295D3350E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace as well? Are you sure its failing in the try block?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to the question itself please?

Comment: You are clearly catching the exception when posting to server, but it looks like it is thrown after that... Somewhere in here.  Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/Deepanshu/Desktop/VIDS_1cam/UI_1cam.py", line 221, in set_frame headers=self.headers)

Comment: @AnwarHusain, you got any idea how I can get way with it?

Comment: Difficult to suggest a solution without seeing the entire code.